# MongoDB: How to group by field and get the most recent result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following data in a MongoDB collection

```
[
  {name: "weight", value: 95,  date: "2014-11-07"},
  {name: "hips",   value: 105, date: "2014-02-06"},
  {name: "weight", value: 89,  date: "2014-05-12"}
]
```

I am trying to get the following data back:

The **value** of each **name** with the most recent **date**:

```
[
  {_id: "weight", value: 95,  date: "2014-11-07"},
  {_id: "hips",   value: 105, date: "2014-02-06"}
]
```

I've looked into aggregation:

```
group: {
  _id: "$name",
  date: { $max: "$date" }
}
```

But i am not getting the result that i want. I need the **value** of what was found

```
[
  {_id: "weight", date: "2014-11-07"},
  {_id: "hips",   date: "2014-02-06"}
]
```

How do I ask mongo to return the value in this aggregation? or is aggregation the wrong approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "date" value is not really helping you here. You should be using a [BSON date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) rather than a "string" which you currently have. At least you strings a "lexical", so they will sort properly.

The principles are basically the same though. You need the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to get the results. The main operations here are to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by the date and use the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) [grouping operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) with the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage:

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
        // Sort on the date per grouping key
        { "$sort": { "name": 1, "date": 1 } },

        // Then group
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "value": { "$first": "$value" },
            "date": { "$first": "$date" }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {
        // do something with results
    }
)
```

The [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator only works on singular values. For "whole rows" or other associated values you need to "sort" and use operators like [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I am still confused about how to retrieve the VALUE field in the end result.

Comment: @simonwjackson Sorry. Missed that. Edited to include. The concept is the same. It's a `$sort` first then use the `$first` operator to obtain the "first" match on the grouping boundary. This applies to all fields you want.